# Getting an dict by name with in a list with an element key within a variable

Tags: python, json

```
data = {
  "items" : [{"potion" : 1}, {"potion2" : 1}]
}

print(data["items"][0]["potion"])
```

So, here's the jiz. I want to get potion2 without providing number like `[0]` but i can't because some variables has 5 items within the list while another one might have 3 items so providing a number might not giving me what i need. Is there a way to get `potion2` without providing that number before it?

Comment: Do you really need a list of single-entry dictionaries?  This makes things more difficult.  Why not just have **"items" : {"potion" : 1, "potion2" : 1}** so that you could retrieve them by name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't want to provide the index because hard coding it will not work in all circumstances.

You can just pull out any items in the list which have that key.

Build a list of any items, which have that key. It might ordinarily be just one, but the container itself does not enforce that only one entry can have that key.

After that you can either iterate over the list or check if the returned value is empty and just take the first element.

```
>>> data = {'items': [{'potion': 1}, {'potion2': 1}]}
>>> e = filter(lambda i: 'potion' in i, data['items'])
>>> for i in e:
...     print(i['potion'])
... 
1
```

Or to pull out only the first element. I realize you said no indices, but this index is applied to the filtered list and we check that its not empty first, so it's a valid thing to do.

```
>>> if e:
...     print(e[0]['potion'])
... 
1
```